# Framer Motion not allowing element to animate in after another element exits

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

I am trying to use Framer Motion with React to have one page animate out and have the next page animate in. I can get each one to work individually, but if I have both set then only the exit animation plays and the next page just snaps in without animating. This is the affected component (some explanatory notes below):

```
const Room = (props) => {
    
    // get load direction from URL params
    const urlparams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const d = urlparams.get("d");
    var outPos = getOutPosition(d);

    // return page as JSX
    return (
        <motion.div
            className="testroom"
            id='currentRoom'
            initial={{ x: outPos[0], y:outPos[1] }}
            animate={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
            transition={{ duration: 1 }}
            exit={props.exitAnimation}
        >
            {props.children}
        </motion.div>
    )
}
```

The exitAnimation prop is passed by a function called on the page using the component, and is an object with attributes x and y, each of which is only ever either '0%' or '100%'. the function getOutPosition returns an array with two elements of the same possible values. I have confirmed that both of these always return expected values.

If the code is left as shown above, the exit animation plays but the next page with the same component does not animate on creation. If I comment out the exit attribute, the entry animation plays correctly.

Comment: You may want to check `<AnimatePresence>`